# Sublime Text 3 usage keymap user

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, sublimetext3

How to embed current file path in a custom user keymap?  I'm referring to this documentation:

http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html

Which has been deprecated but I do not see equivalent documentation for `$file_path` variable which I need to use in my keymap in the latest documentation.  I'm not having any luck.  My keymap looks like this (trying to launch Google Chrome with flag to package my application):

```
{
    "keys": [
        "shift+ctrl+g"
    ],
    "command": "exec",
    "args": {
        "cmd": [
            "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe",
            "--pack-extension=${file_path}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation is here: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html

You may toggle the version switch in the bottom of the sidebar. The `$file_path` variable still exists though, so it probably should work. You may try removing the wrapping braces `{` and `}`

Comment: I've been testing this and can get the external tool to execute properly if I fix the argument to:

    "--pack-extension=C:\\Users\\App\\YouTube Videos"

This doesn't work though:

    "--pack-extension=$file_path"